# CGAffineTransformRotate size issues

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, rotation, cgaffinetransform

i'm developing an application that allows the user to rotate the needles of a clock. for that i'm using the transform property of the needle's imageview :

`CGAffineTransform newTrans = CGAffineTransformRotate(initialTransform, -angleDif);
minutesNeedle.transform = newTrans;`

for the purpose of detecting the user's touch i must detect the needle's space (minute or hour's frame). And here my problem show off, after rotating the image it looks like the image is stretched and interfere with the other image. the UIView class documentation says that after being transformed the view's frame changes and you must use center and bounds properties. However, i cannot use the bounds property to detect the touches user which are located in the superview.

is there any other way to do this animation without changing the frame size (i doubt). Or can i resize the frame in the touchesEnded method (i've tried but in vain). Please help i'm blocking there for one week!! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems like you can avoid this conflict altogether.  Create a separate view for handling touches, independent of the needle view.  On a touch event, move the needle view appropriately.  This separate view would be the size of the clock essentially and be overlaid on the other views, having a clear background.  It would have a delegate with appropriate callbacks so your view controller (or whatever owns the needle) can adjust it.

As far as what the callbacks would be, I would just forward the touch events like:

```
    - (void)touchReceiverView:(TouchReceiverView *)view didReceiveTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

Comment: i'm not sure that i understand what you're trying to say. However i've already tried to create a view that will hold my needle, then i transform the view (not the needle's image), the size of the image stand correctly but the coordinates of the image are relative to the view holding it. so x and y are wrong for the user's axis. Thanks for the reply

Comment: I mean create a blank/clear view in addition to the view that holds the needle.  Overlay that on top of the clock and use touch events on that view to control the animation of the needle view.

Comment: in the touchesMoved method i'm testing if the touche's user is in the needle's frame (if (CGRectContainsPoint(needle.frame, touch)). In this case how would i detect the needle's frame with the original size in the blank view?

Comment: You should have a view controller that owns the needle view and also the blank view.  The view controller will be the one performing the transformations, so it can keep track of whatever frames you need.  The blank view forwards touch events to the view controller via a delegate callback, this triggers movement of the needle when it is appropriate.  You'll have to convert the points from the blank view to the needle view when testing/calculating.

Answer (score 0):

Do it with CALayers is WAY much easier and performance is better this way.

```
CALayer *handLayer = [CALayer layer];
handLayer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"hand.png"].CGImage;
handLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5,0.0)];
[myview.layer addSublayer:handLayer];

//i.e.: if handLayer represents the seconds hand then repeat this every second ;)
handLayer.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation (angle); //set the angle here
```

Someone wrote a [ClockView sample using CALayers](https://github.com/nacho4d/ClockView), maybe you find it useful.

Comment: i've tried this with CALayer, unfortunately i get the same problem..when i apply a rotating trasform, the layer's size is also changing!! i want to keep the same size and location to detect exactly the user touch and do my rotation if(CGRectContainsPoint(needle.frame, touch))!! Thanks